# How to tell if user selected an autocomplete option in a form?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, ajax

I created a form that has an autocomplete field of registered users and it is attached to nodes. In the form validation function I check if the string of the `textfield` is a valid user but in order to reduce the server load I also need to check if the selected option (current field value) is an option of the autocomplete set of options by Javascript.

I found [How can you tell if a suggestion was selected from JQuery UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517188/how-can-you-tell-if-a-suggestion-was-selected-from-jquery-ui-autocomplete) but it gave me no clue to the solution.

How can I do that?

This is my module code :

```
function recommend_form($form,$form_state){
    $form = array();
    $form['username'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#description' => t('Please enter a username using autocomplete widget'),
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#size' => 20,
            '#autocomplete_path' => 'recommend/autocomplete',
    );
    return $form;
}

function recommend_menu(){
    $items['recommend/autocomplete'] = array(
        'title' => 'Autocomplete for users',
        'page callback' => '_users_autocomplete',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
} 
function _users_autocomplete($string){
    $matches = array();
    $result = db_select('users', 'c')
    ->fields('c', array('name'))
    ->condition('name', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $matches[$row->name] = check_plain($row->name);
    }
    drupal_json_output($matches);
}

function recommend_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    global $user;
    if($user->uid != 0){
        $form = drupal_get_form("recommend_form");
        $node->content['a_new_field'] = array(
                '#markup' => drupal_render($form),
                '#weight' => 10,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is seems ambiguous :(, according to your code I see your create a form with  user autocomplete text field and attach it in `node_view`, then? what you want  to do after it ? please tell me more about it
"I see that you are from Iran for the first time(maybe you didn't specified your location  or I didn't  look at your profile ,by the way I am so happy that Iranian have activity here,"Chakerim" ;) "

Comment: @zhilevan mokhlesam daash ;) . I want to attach a form with autocomplete text field of users to every node of the website, this code does this. after submission some processes will be done

Comment: fadat dash;),  I see it, You just add a autocomplete field ( contain users ) in view of node and after that what ? why you want do that? I don't see any submit handler and all thing you did is adding a autocomplete field without anything after it . my question is what is your aim ? ( Are you want add user to any node?if yes where this data will be saved ? (do you consider a field in that content type or some where ?)... , tell me more  what you want in final, explain your scenario more please ;)

Comment: It is just a module that recommend nodes to other users

Comment: good, but do you consider where the selected user in autocomplete field saved?( I think some thing is missed here)

Comment: did you find your solution?

Comment: @zhilevan I was on trip for a few days. No I didn't, There is no ambiguity in the question. There is a form with an autocomplete text field of users and I need to know if the user selected an option from the aucomplete widget

Comment: @zhilevan thanks you very much for your help, The user selects an option from the autocomplete and then click on the submit button. This is not important what happens after submission I only need to know if the selected option is from autocomplete widget or not. The only way I found so far is to load all of the usernames then by jQuery check if the selected user is a valid one or not.

Comment: It is strange I can't tag you in comment :) , ok let's clear the scenario "you create a autocomplete textfield(user list) and attach it in node view , and want each user suggest that node to user(s) , but my big question is when user select a user is list what happened after there is no submit button,there is no field to save data, there is no ajax ." So after What?.

Comment: @zhilevan my code is not complete, I removed the rest of it when I copied it in here. that part is not important

Comment: you removed the problem my friend, the code that comes in question is ok but there is not specified you aim and what you want, , would you please comes the submit handler ? I think you want create a suggestion method that each user can suggest the node to another user .but really I dont see anything to do this ( it is just a autocomplete with nothing after it )